# Hiding EmberJS Route instead of Destoying

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

Is there a way to hide templates of EmberJS routes instead of destroy them?

There are a lot of old post about this but still no official way to achieve this.

Comment: No. Why do you need it?

Comment: I have four tabs which are linked to different routes. Using hide instead of destroy would be much faster.

Comment: Actually not. Having less DOM is usually better then hiding a lot of DOM. Leave the performance optimization to glimmer. Is there something special you're rending, that takes long to render? Because a usual template should render like in no-time.

Comment: I agree with @Lux

Comment: Each of the four tabs contains a list. An empty list renders in around 100ms (according to EmberJS Inspector). An item list renders in around 15ms. So when the list has 60 items, it takes 1 second... There are no ajax calls for the data as everything is already loaded.